# Visual Studio can't switch accounts when connecting to Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, azure-devops

[image: After signing in, the web explorer frame brings me to the profile account of Visual Studio online.]

I have different accounts with different VSO subscriptions. I'm trying to connect to a different account (from the one I'm logged in VS-2015) so that I can check in code in the repository that I have in that account. But when trying this, Visual Studio brings me to the profile website, from which is basically a dead end - what am I supposed to do from there?

The "Connect to Team Foundation Server screen sometimes just freezes after authentication, and doesn't go anywhere from there.

Comment: Do you mean it opens the profile website when click switch user link in Connect To Team Foundation Server window? What's the detail version of your VS 2015? You can try to update your VS 2015 to least version. On the other hand, you may try to clear user data by using devenv /resetuserdata command.

Comment: I did update to the last version (Update 3) and that didn't help. But clearing the user data did help. I was just about to write it as the answer to my own question and I saw your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So clearing the settings file, which is named CurrentSettings usually in the folder C:\Users\your user name \Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Settings (Windows) - helped get passed this issue.

Also, when you are brought to the VSO Profile page (the one I showed in my picture question) you have to select the project you are trying to open.